# Override JAXB annotation Mapping with MOXY oxm binding file

Tags: xml, jaxb, marshalling, moxy

I'm trying to implement two differents mappings for certains of my objects.

The first mapping is done using JAXB annotations on my classes. It's working fine.

The second mapping is really simple : it should take every Java attribute.
To do this I wrote a very simple xml bindings file :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml-bindings xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/oxm"
package-name="com.foo" xml-mapping-metadata-complete="true">
<java-types>
    <java-type name="com.foo.OverridedMappingClass" xml-accessor-type="FIELD">
    </java-type>
    <java-type name="com.foo.OverridedMappingClass2" xml-accessor-type="FIELD">
    </java-type>
</java-types>
</xml-bindings>
```

The problems come when I try to initialize the JAXBContext :

```
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    List<String> bindings = new ArrayList<String>();
    bindings.add("com/bindings/bindings-foo.xml");
    props.put(JAXBContextProperties.OXM_METADATA_SOURCE, bindings);
    try
    {
        jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[] { OverridedMappingClass, OverridedMappingClass2}, props);
    }
    catch (JAXBException e)
    {
        m_logger.error("Could not build the JAXBContext", e);
    }
```

The following Exception occurres

```
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: 24
 - with linked exception:
[java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 24]
at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext$TypeMappingInfoInput.createContextState(JAXBContext.java:1059)
at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext.<init>(JAXBContext.java:182)
at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory.createContext(JAXBContextFactory.java:165)
at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory.createContext(JAXBContextFactory.java:152)
at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory.createContext(JAXBContextFactory.java:112)
at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory.createContext(JAXBContextFactory.java:102)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:211)
at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:340)
at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:574)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 24
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.libraries.asm.Type.getType(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.libraries.asm.Type.getArgumentTypes(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.libraries.asm.MethodWriter.visitMaxs(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.MappingsGenerator.generateMapEntryClass(MappingsGenerator.java:2003)
at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.MappingsGenerator.generateMapEntryClassAndDescriptor(MappingsGenerator.java:1941)
at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.MappingsGenerator.generateCompositeCollectionMapping(MappingsGenerator.java:2125)
at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.MappingsGenerator.generateMapping(MappingsGenerator.java:798)
at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.MappingsGenerator.generateMappings(MappingsGenerator.java:2464)
at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.MappingsGenerator.generateMappings(MappingsGenerator.java:2424)
at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.MappingsGenerator.generateProject(MappingsGenerator.java:246)
at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.Generator.generateProject(Generator.java:188)
at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext$TypeMappingInfoInput.createContextState(JAXBContext.java:1064)
at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext$TypeMappingInfoInput.createContextState(JAXBContext.java:1056)
... 19 more
```

For information : The classes OverridedMappingClass extend an abstract class from another package. This abstract class is JAXB annotated, how should I manage it ? Do I have to write an XML for every package where a mapped class exists or is there a way to regroup it in the same file ?

I'm using the 3 following bundles from eclipseLink-plugins

```
org.eclipse.persistence.asm_3.3.1.v201302191223.jar
org.eclipse.persistence.core_2.6.0.v20130912-6b5e067.jar
org.eclipse.persistence.moxy_2.6.0.v20130912-6b5e067.jar
```

Any help is welcomed !

Comment: Where you able to solve the problem? I am stuck with exactly the same error as you were getting. Any pointers would be much appreciated. Thanks :).

Comment: Nope, I put this project in hold.
Please, let me know if you figure out a way to manage this issue.

Comment: I'm stuck too. Any progress?

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

External mapping file (bindings-foo.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml-bindings xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/oxm"
    package-name="com.foo" xml-mapping-metadata-complete="true">
    <java-types>
        <java-type name="OverridedMappingClass"
            xml-accessor-type="FIELD">
        </java-type>
        <java-type name="OverridedMappingClass2"
            xml-accessor-type="FIELD">
        </java-type>
    </java-types>
</xml-bindings>
```

Code to create `JAXBContext` on external mapping file:

```java
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<String, Object>(1);
    props.put(JAXBContextProperties.OXM_METADATA_SOURCE, "com/bindings/bindings-foo.xml");
    try
    {
        jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[] { OverridedMappingClass, OverridedMappingClass2}, props);
    }
    catch (JAXBException e)
    {
        m_logger.error("Could not build the JAXBContext", e);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Blaise for answering, but I still have the same Exception raising on the `JAXBContext.newInstance` when using your proposed code.