# Migration from WebLogic 10.3 to 12.1.1

Tags: java, jaxb, weblogic, jax-ws, weblogic12c

I am trying to migrate an application from WebLogic Server 10.3 to 12.1.1. When starting the application I get the following Error.

```
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: 24
with linked exception:
[java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 24]
       at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext$TypeMappingInfoInput.createContextState(JAXBContext.java:832)
       at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext.<init>(JAXBContext.java:143)
       at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory.createContext(JAXBContextFactory.java:142)
       at com.sun.xml.ws.db.toplink.JAXBContextFactory.newContext(JAXBContextFactory.java:180)
       at com.sun.xml.ws.spi.db.BindingContextFactory.create(BindingContextFactory.java:179)
       at com.sun.xml.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl$1.run(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:211)
       at com.sun.xml.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl$1.run(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:185)
       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
       at com.sun.xml.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl.createJAXBContext(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:184)
       at com.sun.xml.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl.postProcess(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:109)
       at com.sun.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.buildRuntimeModel(RuntimeModeler.java:321)
       at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.<init>(DatabindingImpl.java:99)
       at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingProviderImpl.create(DatabindingProviderImpl.java:74)
       at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingProviderImpl.create(DatabindingProviderImpl.java:58)
       at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingFactoryImpl.createRuntime(DatabindingFactoryImpl.java:130)
       at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.createSEIModel(EndpointFactory.java:411)
       at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.createEndpoint(EndpointFactory.java:232)
       at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(WSEndpoint.java:546)
       at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(WSEndpoint.java:525)
       at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(WSEndpoint.java:601)
       at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.JAXWSDeployedServlet.getEndpoint(JAXWSDeployedServlet.java:183)
       at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.JAXWSServlet.registerEndpoint(JAXWSServlet.java:139)
       at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.JAXWSServlet.init(JAXWSServlet.java:68)
       at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.JAXWSDeployedServlet.init(JAXWSDeployedServlet.java:54)
       at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:240)
       at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:299)
       at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:250)
       at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
       at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
       at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
       at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.initServletInstance(StubSecurityHelper.java:94)
       at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.createServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:82)
       at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.createOneInstance(StubLifecycleHelper.java:74)
       at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.<init>(StubLifecycleHelper.java:60)
       at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.<init>(StubLifecycleHelper.java:34)
       at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.initStubLifecycleHelper(ServletStubImpl.java:624)
       at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.prepareServlet(ServletStubImpl.java:565)
       at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadServlet(WebAppServletContext.java:1874)
       at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.loadServletsOnStartup(WebAppServletContext.java:1848)
       at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1738)
       at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:2740)
       at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1704)
       at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:781)
       at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:213)
       at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:208)
       at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:35)
       at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:70)
       at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.start(ScopedModuleDriver.java:212)
       at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:111)
       at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
       at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:213)
       at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:208)
       at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:35)
       at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:70)
       at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:24)
       at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:729)
       at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:35)
       at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:258)
       at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.activate(EarDeployment.java:61)
       at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165)
       at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:79)
       at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:582)
       at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:148)
       at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:114)
       at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.StartOperation.doCommit(StartOperation.java:149)
       at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:335)
       at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:844)
       at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1253)
       at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:440)
       at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:163)
       at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195)
       at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
       at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:68)
       at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:545)
       at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
       at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 24
       at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.libraries.asm.Type.getType(Unknown Source)
       at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.libraries.asm.Type.getArgumentTypes(Unknown Source)
       at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.libraries.asm.MethodWriter.visitMaxs(Unknown Source)
       at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.MappingsGenerator.generateMapEntryClass(MappingsGenerator.java:1546)
       at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.MappingsGenerator.generateMapEntryClassAndDescriptor(MappingsGenerator.java:1484)
       at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.MappingsGenerator.generateMapMapping(MappingsGenerator.java:1459)
       at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.MappingsGenerator.generateMapping(MappingsGenerator.java:477)
       at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.MappingsGenerator.generateMappings(MappingsGenerator.java:2033)
       at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.MappingsGenerator.generateMappings(MappingsGenerator.java:1994)
       at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.MappingsGenerator.generateProject(MappingsGenerator.java:195)
       at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.Generator.generateProject(Generator.java:174)
       at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext$TypeMappingInfoInput.createContextState(JAXBContext.java:837)<24.06.2014 16:42 Uhr MESZ> <Error> <HTTP> <BEA-101216> <Servlet: "xy" failed to preload on startup in Web application: "report.server".
com.sun.xml.ws.spi.db.DatabindingException: 24
       at com.sun.xml.ws.db.toplink.JAXBContextFactory.newContext(JAXBContextFactory.java:185)
       at com.sun.xml.ws.spi.db.BindingContextFactory.create(BindingContextFactory.java:179)
       at com.sun.xml.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl$1.run(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:211)
       at com.sun.xml.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl$1.run(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:185)
       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
       Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: 24
- with linked exception:
[java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 24]
       at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext$TypeMappingInfoInput.createContextState(JAXBContext.java:832)
       at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext.<init>(JAXBContext.java:143)
       at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory.createContext(JAXBContextFactory.java:142)
       at com.sun.xml.ws.db.toplink.JAXBContextFactory.newContext(JAXBContextFactory.java:180)
       at com.sun.xml.ws.spi.db.BindingContextFactory.create(BindingContextFactory.java:179)
       Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 24
       at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.libraries.asm.Type.getType(Unknown Source)
       at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.libraries.asm.Type.getArgumentTypes(Unknown Source)
       at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.libraries.asm.MethodWriter.visitMaxs(Unknown Source)
       at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.MappingsGenerator.generateMapEntryClass(MappingsGenerator.java:1546)
       at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.MappingsGenerator.generateMapEntryClassAndDescriptor(MappingsGenerator.java:1484)
       Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
> 

       at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext$TypeMappingInfoInput.createContextState(JAXBContext.java:830)
       ... 75 more
```

Additional Information:

- The unmodified code works just fine in WebLogic Server 12.1.2.
  Unfortunately I have to use WLS 12.1.1.
- We are using JAX-WS
- We are using JDK 7

If any additional information is required let me know.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What do you mean by "starting the application" do you mean the web service or the client pointing to the web service?

Comment: We have a server application which uses JAX-WS. If we want to deploy this application we get this error message. Does that clarify the situation?

Comment: Can you provide details about your object model?

Comment: For reference, here is what Blaise is looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20525192/override-jaxb-annotation-mapping-with-moxy-oxm-binding-file

Comment: Hi all. I just got two more ideas that I am trying out. I am starting to realize that you might need more information to help and I have to check how to provide it if my new ideas don't work. If I solve the problem I will of course post the answer!

Answer (score 1):

I am facing the same problem and the bug was supposed to be fixed in the Eclipselink ASM module in version 2.6.0 (https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=429992).

I upgrade the eclipselink JARs in weblogic, I packaged the JARs but the bug doesn't seem to be fixed. The only way I got my webservices back working after upgrading to Weblogic 12 is by not using MOXy at all. 
You can do this by either loading databinding.override_1.2.0.0.jar in the weblogic classpath (system wide fix) or to define the services in your own EAR and tell weblogic to use the resources in the EAR.

In short, add a file named "com.sun.xml.ws.spi.db.BindingContextFactory" to src/main/resources/META-INF/services in your ear project and add the following line in it

```
com.sun.xml.ws.db.glassfish.JAXBRIContextFactory
```

and a file named javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext with the following content

```
com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory
```

Add the following lines to your weblogic-application.xml:

```
<prefer-application-resources>
    <resource-name>META-INF/services/com.sun.xml.ws.spi.db.BindingContextFactory</resource-name>
    <resource-name>META-INF/services/javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext</resource-name>
</prefer-application-resources>
```

And package jaxb in your application:

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
 <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
 <version>2.2.11</version>
</dependency>
```

If maven doesn't add your xml files to the EAR, make sure to add this to the configuration of the maven-ear-plugin:

```
<earSourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</earSourceDirectory>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar trouble with WLS 12c and i followed the instruction to add the changes in my ear package. The details is [in this link](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/WSGET/jax-ws-datatypes.htm#WSGET347).

Is similar to the solution gave by @P_W999 and there is a solution for the server scope or the application scope.